# sort multiple data.tables and fill in correct values

Tags: r, data.table

I have 4 data.tables, I need a final table with merged value1-value4 in it.

Table 1 has 4 cases and 5 different timepoints and value1.

table 1:

| case | time | value1 | value2 | value3 | value4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2019-11-10 | 1 | NA | NA | NA |
| A | 2019-11-09 | 2 | NA | NA | NA |
| B | 2018-11-10 | 3 | NA | NA | NA |
| C | 2017-11-10 | 4 | NA | NA | NA |
| D | 2016-11-10 | 5 | NA | NA | NA |

Table 2 has the same 4 cases and the same 5 timepoints (with different order) and value2/value3 and value4.

table 2:

| case | time | value1 | value2 | value3 | value4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2019-11-10 | NA | 8 | NA | NA |
| C | 2017-11-10 | NA | 6 | NA | NA |
| D | 2016-11-10 | NA | 9 | NA | NA |
| B | 2018-11-10 | NA | 7 | NA | NA |
| A | 2019-11-09 | NA | 10 | NA | NA |

table3 and table 4:

same as before, table3 has value3 and table4 has value4

The final table should contain all 4 cases with the correct timepoints and value1 of table 1 / value2 of table2 and so on... How is it possible to create the final table with filled value1-value4?

table result:

| case | time | value1 | value2 | value3 | value4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2019-11-10 | 1 | 8 | 3 | 4 |
| A | 2019-11-09 | 2 | 10 | 3 | 4 |
| B | 2018-11-10 | 3 | 7 | 3 | 4 |
| C | 2017-11-10 | 4 | 6 | 3 | 4 |
| D | 2016-11-10 | 5 | 9 | 3 | 4 |

Comment: You can use a left join.

Answer (score 0):

With `data.table`:

```
data1 <- read.table(text='case  time    value1  value2
A   2019-11-10  1   NA
A   2019-11-09  2   NA
B   2018-11-10  3   NA
C   2017-11-10  4   NA
D   2016-11-10  5   NA',header=T)

data2 <- read.table(text='case  time    value1  value2
A   2019-11-10  1   8
A   2019-11-09  2   10
B   2018-11-10  3   7
C   2017-11-10  4   6
D   2016-11-10  5   9',header=T)

library(data.table)
setDT(data1)
setDT(data2)

data1[data2,on=.(case,time),.(case,time,value1,value2=i.value2,value1=x.value1)]

     case       time value1 value2 value1
   <char>     <char>  <int>  <int>  <int>
1:      A 2019-11-10      1      8      1
2:      A 2019-11-09      2     10      2
3:      B 2018-11-10      3      7      3
4:      C 2017-11-10      4      6      4
5:      D 2016-11-10      5      9      5
```